# Eclipse Android GUI Editor: Show IDs?

Tags: android, user-interface, adt

I am using the eclipse (adt plugin) android gui editor and I am wondering how one can display all the used IDs for the single views at once? Currently Iam looking it up by right clicking and choosing Edit ID, is there an easier way to just always show the IDs while the editor is displayed? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But you can make a feature request for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to the XML Edit Window.

But I think that the right click on the view is the easiest way

Comment: that's sad, I expected the editor to be better... but thanks for your reply :-)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the tool from the abd [hierarchy](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html)

That gives you a grear overview of your UI application.

Comment: thank you, my layout isn't very omplex, so that's maybe overkill for my case. just sad, that the editor doesn't include this functionaity. thanks for your reply!